# How secure is it to block IP addresses in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, security, .htaccess

I have one webserver which hosts several different sites. Some are used by external customers and some are only used internally. For the internal sites, I have an .htaccess file which denies all IP address but allows any IP address that starts with 10.25.x.x.

```
IndexIgnore *
deny from all
allow from 10.25.
```

This means only a PC our local network can access the server. Even if the customer has a local IP address of 10.25.x.x on their computer, my webserver should only see their public IP, right?

I have no forms that upload files to this directory so they shouldn't be able to overwrite the .htaccess file.

My question is: Is there any way an attacker can bypass these security methods? If so, what preventive measures can I take to ensure that doesn't happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer of Sébastien Renauld shows that IP black/white listing is not perfect to secure your websites. Your application should already be secure enough for a public accessible deployment. Anyways, IP restrictions do help limiting the attack vectors on your application.

Keep in mind that IP spoofing is technically possible, but is pretty difficult to perform.

From outside of the network, a hacker has to bypass at least the following obstacles.

- Any ISP logic that removes faulty IP packets (aka, having an IP address which is not the same as the senders IP.)
- Any firewall/gateway/router on your side that drops these packets. Usually internal and external networks are separated, and packets are not easily routed between this networks.
- HTTP uses the TCP protocol, which includes a [three way handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) as part of the connection setup. This means that the sender needs to acknowledge the the connection as well. In short: this connection setup uses an arbitrary number to synchronize the server and the clients communication. An hacker needs to guess this number, send it at the correct moment.

There are many more obstacles than I just summed up which need to bypassed by an attacker, like preventing a local, legitimate client not interfering with the attack. (Think about where the responses to the spoofed IP adress of the server will go to, and what the impersonated client will do.)

The easier way of spoofing an IP address, is doing it from within the network itself. Well, if that is already possible, you probably have some other things to look into first :)

I hope you will see that it is practically not feasible that an hacker will perform this attack these days. Security is a balance between the effort needed and the satisfaction gained by an attacker.

Therefore I would say that IP white listing, next to binding at the local network as Sébastien Renauld suggests, is a good enough security practice. You still need to assume that an attacker can gain access to your internal network, and therefor should also look into the security of your websites and server themselves.

Answer (score 4):

The bottom line of your question is: **DO NOT, *EVER*, RELY ON THE VALUE OF AN IP**.

To demonstrate and illustrate this point, [**this document**](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ip-spoofing-introduction) here explains how an IP address actually is attached to a data packet. Effectively, it is just a list of bytes for the source, and a list of bytes for the destination. Anyone can effectively modify those (this is, amongst other things, what NAT does, by the way, and NAT traversal would not work otherwise). What this means is that, if they can be modified, they can be spoofed.

There are ways to ward against this partially, but all the methods rely on heuristics. For example, the simplest rule is that if a packet came from your WAN interface yet claims to be from `192.168.0.1`, you know that something is up. Some security devices on the market do exactly this: they filter out what they think is dubious.

In your case, there is a way to ward off against all this. I assume you are using Apache. If you are, instead of binding your `VirtualHost` to all interfaces (As is the default in Apache: `*:80`), bind it to that specific local interface (`10.0.0.0:80` or equivalent). This will force Apache to only listen for pings on that interface, which, if running unix/linux, is segregated from the other interfaces and guaranteed to be distinct. This allows you to have a LAN-only website, effectively.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm running Apache on a Windows 2008 server using XAMPP. Do you think the VirtualHost approach will still be effective?

Comment: OT: This is a nice introduction. I like it.

Comment: @Carson: More effective than htaccess filtering. While it won't be spoof-proof, all you now need to add is an ISA upstream (or PIX firewall), both of them support ingress filtering. From there, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are. [IP Spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) is possible. Remember that everyone can change the metadata of a packet he sends.

There are little to no preventive methods that can help you there except for a completely different approach on authentification I fear. You cannot achieve effective security with .htaccess blacklisting((or rather whitelisting, in your case) only. [Ingress filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingress_filtering) is a must however.

Comment: It's even possible to spoof a public IP address to look like a local IP? I thought local addresses (10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x, etc) were reserved only for LANs?

Comment: @KennyJohnson: Depends on the nodes you will be hitting on the way. If you are one node away from the target in terms of network and the target does not have a device capable of ingress filtering, as Carson specified.

Comment: Remember that the IP is just a number inside the header of some packet. It can be handcrafted and who prevents the attacker from signing with 10.x.x.x? Many ISPs block this by network ingress filtering but I would not rely on that. If you'll have to do it with .htaccess only(which I discourage), inspect every packet that comes from outside thoroughly.

Comment: ...Or bind Apache to your local-only interface, which is one step better than having Apache bind on everything and trust everything. This is another solution, which is mildly more secure on Windows, and a lot more secure on *nix.

Comment: If I bind Apache to the local-only interface would that effect the entire server or can I limit that to only certain directories? We have 2 websites on the server which need to remain available to the public.

Comment: @KennyJohnson: this will limit your VirtualHost and all the contents of it. This does not, however, limit Apache entirely.